# Can I get notifications of immediate replies when not subscribed to a channel?

Tags: notifications, slack

I belong to several channels & teams on slack.  Sometimes I make a comment on a channel that I'm not subscribed but nobody answers immediately.  I go back a few hours later and find someone replied but I wasn't notified.

Has anyone come up with a solution other than asking people to mention you in replies?